# Comparing strings and if on C

Tags: c, string, if-statement, numbers

I need to make a code which compare strings and assign a number for a string. 
I did this :

```
int metd=0;
if (strcmp( metodo, "GET")==1){
    metd=1;
}
if (strcmp( metodo, "HEAD")==1){
    metd=2;
}
if (strcmp( metodo, "PUT")==1){
    metd=3;
}
if (strcmp( metodo, "DELETE")==1){
    metd=4;
}
```

But at the end, metd always is 4. Some ideas?

Comment: I have an idea or two. First - when things like this don't work, use a debugger before posting your issue to the Internet. Second - when you discover (through use of your debugger) that a function such as `strcmp()` isn't doing what you expect it to do, read its documentation before posting your issue to the Internet. People are very happy to help but they want you to take some minimal steps to help yourself first.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry... I debugged before posting, but i saw a strange behave (the correct functionality of the function ). Next time i'll try to get the docummentation too before posting.

Answer (score 6):

[strcmp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) returns `0` when both the strings are same not `1`

Comment: Nice answer, all is needed is the link to the manual page, and the will to read it... By the way I like this [`strcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) more, because there are no ad's and it's more pleasant to read, take a look... And you just need to google for `man7 strcmp` ...

Comment: @iharob Long time !! Thanks I added your link :)